# User is not authorized in MEAN Stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am using mean-cli package to build a MEAN.io application.Already the mean-cli package contains build in  core package "Articles" it performs default CRUD operation and API's, I am trying to access that API call during Article creation suggest me what are the default param needs to be send for Article creation.

Comment: Can you share which resource are you following to learn this? Your question isn't sufficient to help you.

Comment: I am following the official http://learn.mean.io/ to set up mean-cli application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because I passed Basic in Header.

Resolved the Issue by passing "Authorization" with "Bearer" token_value 
in Headers section of Postman Rest client.

Example,
Authorization: Bearer token_value

Comment: Your question didn't really explain 'The issue' that you seemed to have fixed. Please try to elaborate your questions with code samples next time you post.